# c# Input string was in incorrect format error when data reading

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqldatareader

so this is my problem.

this function:

```
    public int Reader(string query, string value, int id, int reader)
    {
        CloseConnection();
        int i = 0;
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(value, id);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (sdr.Read())
        {
            i = sdr.GetInt16(reader);
            con.Close();
        }
        return i;
    }
```

is supposed to data read mysql command and it works, excpet for this line:

```
 string str = Convert.ToString(mysqlquery.Reader("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=@id", "@id", i, 2));
```

the other lines look exact the same, and only this one doesn't work.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chnrC.png) is how my database looks.

EDIT

replacing the 2 in the en of the line is oke

example:

```
  string str = Convert.ToString(mysqlquery.Reader("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id=@id", "@id", i, 1));
```

Comment: You are selecting 3 columns.  how do you expect Convert to know to fetch 3 pieces if data from the reader?  Read each data element first

Comment: Well, column 2 (in 0-based column numbering) is the name - you're trying to fetch the name value with `GetInt16`, which is not going to work.

Comment: @JonSkeet could you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Well we don't know whether you're *trying* to read the name column, or whether you just have an off-by-one error. It's an odd method to start with though, as it can only read 16-bit integers...

Comment: @JonSkeet oh sorry I was being stupid the items in my database are string and I am asking my program to get a int i should change it to sdr.GetString(reader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a complex object, probably an array of sorts. Try accessing the index of the array, then doing the conversion to string.